# Google Chrome / web browser extension: fitering requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I recently created a extension for Chrome browser, which simply redirects calls from one URL to another.

So, I needed to add permissions below:

```
"permissions": ["webRequestBlocking", "webRequest", "*://learn.microsoft.com/*"]
```

To redirect URL I added such event handler:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (event) => { 
    if ( event.url.includes("/pl-pl/")) {
      return { redirectUrl: event.url.replace("/pl-pl/", "/en-us/") }; 
    }
  },
  {urls: ["*://learn.microsoft.com/*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Clearly, I want to capture calls to `docs.microsoft`, but I specified it twice.

My question is: are those rules equivalent?

I tested it and it's enough to specify it only in manifest file, but do they work the same way internally?

Or maybe specifying it twice causes double validation and worsens performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The URL permission in manifest.json is allowing the extension to process these URLs via any API, not just webRequest, but since you don't need anything else and only use a single URL pattern, you can indeed specify `["<all_urls>"]` in webRequest listener registration for simplicity.
2. The performance impact of checking the URL twice inside the native C++ code of the browser shouldn't be detectable in such a simple case especially if compared to the task of activating JavaScript context to run your listener, which consumes thousands of times more CPU cycles.

Potential improvements:

- The fastest solution is [chrome.declarativeWebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest).
  For this case you would need RedirectByRegEx action I guess.
- If the goal is to avoid duplication, you can use chrome.runtime.getManifest:

  ```
  {urls: chrome.runtime.getManifest().permissions.filter(p => p.includes('/'))}
  ```

  The only pitfall is that `"permissions"` don't require the last `*` in hosts as they ignore the path part so make sure to always add it in manifest.json.